# Java Functional testing

Tags: java, user-interface, automated-tests

I have a Java application that has a GUI for user interactions.

The GUI is implemented with SWT.

Now I want to make some Functional Tests for the application. As whitebox as possible.

I have been trying some frameworks like Maveryx, and SWTbot. But Maveryx is just a pain to configure and it didn't seem to integrate very well with a CI server. SWTBot I simply wasn't able to get it to find all the necessary classes after installing it on eclipse.

I would like to know what are other people using to test their Java GUI applications. And if possible to point me towards some tutorials about that frameworks.

Comment: Why not specific problem about swtbot here.  I would have thought it worked well with eclipse.

Comment: i have installed the plugin, but my project uses maven for dependency management. And whenever i try to write tests with it it says it can't find SWTBot's classes. And there is no Maven Artifact for SWTbot.

Comment: I don't consider this question opinion based. I just _need_ to find out what is being used by other people to address these situations, since I can not find suitable resources on google.

Comment: @ Thiago Veloso. My vote is to move to programmers.. site.

Comment: I don't mind it being moved. Can a mod do that? Or should I just repost this on the other site?

Answer (score 1):

Ours is awt/swing/java2d  application . We use [jemmy](http://prokop.uek.krakow.pl/projects/download/jemmy_introduction.pdf) for it.  According to the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jemmy/info) it works with SWT as well. Please give it a try.

If you are willing to pay some money, [Rational Functional Tester](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.rational.test.ft.proxy.api.help/ProxyApiReference/com/rational/test/ft/domain/java/swt/package-summary.html) (very expensive) or [Squish](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/tutorial-getting-started-java_swt.html) could be considered.  Both are very good products, squish is significantly cheaper (or it used to be)

Comment: Your presentation says it lacks tutorials and it sure does. I am finding it hard to get started with SWT testing.